# Retrospective templates for implementations?

Tags: postmortem, retrospective

[(Related question).](https://pm.stackexchange.com/questions/1307/how-do-you-share-lessons-learned-from-a-post-mortem)

I have recently landed myself a product engineer role.
The software product is a server based product with a front end GUI in the browser.
We have a number of clients, but the product is still growing and the developers/product manager are still working on bug fixes and enhancements.

We have around 20 staff that will go out to our existing or new clients and help roll out the product within their environments.

As far as I can see, the methodology is to just go in there and get the job done.

I need a bit more experience with implementing the product outside of the lab, but already I feel there would be a lot of benefit if there was a better system in place:

- Methodology (apart from the manual) to get the product installed. I.e. A tick-list on things to check before leaving the site.
- Retrospective (is this the right word?) for each implementation to gather what went right/wrong. This would then be shared on our internal Wiki (Confluence).

**Does anyone have any good resources, such as templates, that I could use to get started?**

Answer (score 1):

There are a few ideas here::
http://agileretrospectivewiki.org/index.php?title=Retrospective_Plans

I really recommend reading 'Agile Retrospectives' - lots of great ideas for a variety of situations.
http://pragprog.com/book/dlret/agile-retrospectives

Answer (score 0):

Hey have you ever heard about this website called [RetroMat](https://plans-for-retrospectives.com/en/)

A lot of cool ideas here

Comment: Link-only answers are discouraged due to the possibility of link decay. Please include the relevant bits from the link in your answer itself in addition to providing the link.